# Import from windows to Hive, ParseException line 1:0 cannot recognize input near 'into' '<EOF>'

Tags: windows, hadoop, import, hive, eof

I am trying to import a file text from my machine windows to Hive. I create a table in Hive and I used this command:

load data local in path `C:\Users\me\Desktop\test.txt` into `test_t` sample;

But it doesn't work, and the Error is:

> Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:69 missing TABLE at 'test_t' near '' line 1:76 extraneous input 'sample' expecting EOF near '' [ERROR_STATUS]

Do you have any advise?

Comment: can you post the create table query in your question and update your question??

Answer (score 0):

you have not mention table in your query
assume- your hive table name is sample

```
load data local inpath "C:\Users\me\Desktop\test.txt" into table sample
```

Comment: even with this command I still get the same Eror :load data local inpath "C:\Users\me\Desktop\hive_test.txt" into table test sample

Comment: what is your table name??